# Strange behavior in PowerShell: Invoking Path.GetFullPath in subscripts return paths relative to the outer script

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, scripting, path

Newbie to PowerShell here. I noticed while writing a script that `Path.GetFullPath()` will return paths relative to the outer script's directory. For example:

```
# In your PowerShell console...
cd ~/Downloads
echo "cd ..;[IO.Path]::GetFullPath('script.ps1')" > script.ps1
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass './script.ps1'
```

prints `C:\Users\You\Downloads\script.ps1` when it *should* print `C:\Users\You\script.ps1` (note the `cd ..`).

Is this a bug in PowerShell, and what are some ways to circumvent this?

Comment: powershell has anything to do with c# or .net?

Comment: @Kelmen If `Path.GetFullPath` is broken, then yes, it does.

Comment: unit test that c# code, simple as that.

Comment: I also noticed that `[IO.Path]::GetFullPath("junk.111")` also returns a path to something that doesn't exist. I'd be very careful making any use of this method in PowerShell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[IO.Path]::GetFullPath('script.ps1')` uses the process's current working directory. That's not the same as powershell's CWD. To change the process's CWD (to get the output you are expecting) you'd have to use a .NET API to change the process CWD as opposed to `cd ..` which is internal to PS.

I'm confident that this isn't a bug, but by design. One reason for the design is that PS has the notion of CWD outside of the file system. So your CWD can be in the registry, in the wsman provider, and in any 3rd party provider plug-in that chooses to implement directories. That can't be mirrored in the process's CWD, since it strictly applies to the file system.

Generally things work pretty well when you mix PS concepts with .NET concepts. However there are some places where there's an impedance mismatch. This is one of them.